# How to Hide Saving .txt file to Database Window Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I created a VBA macro that formats and creates charts out of raw data. I have added functionality to track usage of the macro and record usage (username, timestamp, client name) to a .txt file on our database.

The problem I am running into is that I want the usage tracker to be blind to the end user. However, I am getting windows popping up showing a save bar to the directory path. I've tried searching around for a solution to keep this hidden but I am unable to find any code that I'm able to implement to solve.

I expected the following inputs to hide all windows. I am not quite sure if I need more elaborate code to hide the save window.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False�
```

Here is the code Im using to save usage:

```
'Usage Tracker'
On Error Resume Next

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

''''tracking file location
Dim strFilename As String: strFilename = "\\Ant\dept\CorporateDevelopment\BizDev\In-Shipment\ISO\zz_File_Location\macrotracking.txt"
Dim recordFile As Workbook
Set recordFile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFilename)
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = recordFile.Sheets("macrotracking").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

wb.Activate
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = "Performance" Then
        exists = True
    End If
Next i

If exists Then
    Advertiser_Name = Sheets("Performance").Range("C3").Value
    Else
    Advertiser_Name = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("J2").Value
End If

MsgBox wb.Name & exists & Advertiser_Name


''''''these are the variables you want to track, just separate by '& ; &'
recordFile.Sheets("macrotracking").Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value = Environ("USERNAME") & ";" & Format(Now(), "m/dd/yyyy") & ";" & Format(Now(), "hh:nn:ss") & ";" & ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value & ";" & "TOTAL"
recordFile.Sheets("macrotracking").Range("A" & LastRow + 1).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A" & LastRow + 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Semicolon:=True
recordFile.Save
recordFile.Close savechanges:=True
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

'End Tracker'
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can help me learn how to hide all windows for this entire macro.

Comment: Are you logging the data to text file or an Excel file?

Comment: You've got a couple things working against each other. The first is that you're opening a ***workbook*** with the file extension ***txt***. This seems to be at cross-purposes. Do you want your result to be a straight text file or an Excel workbook? If you want a simple text file, try using [this code](https://www.devhut.net/2011/06/06/vba-append-text-to-a-text-file/) for a quick and simple append action. Since you're saving the file to a network location, the Windows OS may pop up a window to show the status if the action takes longer.

Comment: Thank you both --- to be honest, I had a team member help with the data tracking piece. There is a workbook on the database folder as well as a .txt. file. I'm not entirely sure why there are both, but it's my understanding the text file is pulling in columns from the workbook, or something, so both are necessary -- though, I'm probably misunderstanding and definitely open to more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: Your question is too confusing for me, but as an aside note: unless you have a very good reason to use `On Error Resume Next` I strongly advise you avoid using it. It *can* be useful in certain cases, but in the code you posted it will just confuse the hell out of you when debugging.

Comment: The question really just boils down to how to not show any pop-up windows to the end user. I provided the code just in case in helped provide an answer on removing pop ups, not necessarily for guidance on the code. As it stands, the code serves its purpose so I wasn't really planning on updating unless there was a simple fix in the code to hide everything. From your experience, is there an easy way to hide all windows (saving to database)? Thanks!